how do I apply custom commit type using release-it?
I've applied release-it custom optiosn as below.
 "release-it": {
    "$schema": "https://unpkg.com/release-it@17/schema/release-it.json",
    "git": {
      "tag": true,
      "push": true,
      "commitMessage": "chore: release v${version}"
    },
    "github": {
      "release": true
    },
    "npm": {
      "publish": false
    },
    "plugins": {
      "@release-it/conventional-changelog": {
        "infile": "CHANGELOG.md",
        "preset": {
          "name": "conventionalcommits",
          "types": [
            {
              "type": "✨ feat",
              "section": "Features"
            },
            {
              "type": " fix",
              "section": "Bug Fixes"
            },
            {
              "type": " docs",
              "section": "Documentation"
            },
            {
              "type": " style",
              "section": "Styles"
            },
            {
              "type": "♻️ refactor",
              "section": "Code Refactoring"
            },
            {
              "type": " cicd",
              "section": "CI/CD"
            },
            {
              "type": "⚡️ perf",
              "section": "Performance Improvements"
            },
            {
              "type": "✅ test",
              "section": "Tests"
            },
            {
              "type": " chore",
              "section": "Chores"
            },
            {
              "type": " settings",
              "section": "Settings"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }

## 0.1.1 (2024-10-20)

I’ve committed using gitMoji for the commit messages,
but the CHANGELOG.md is not generating changes based on the commit types.
Instead, I’m just seeing a version heading without any details:
Am I missing something in my configuration? Shouldn’t the changelog reflect the commit types based on my preset setup?
